# Por qué este código no añade un entero a la lista objetivo nada más sino que lo añade a todas las listas que contiene listaAdyacencias?

Tags: kotlin

```
            File("mini.txt").useLines() { lines -> lines.forEach {lineas.add(it)} }
            for(i in 1..lineas.elementAt(0).toInt()){
                listaAdyacencias.add(listavacia)
            }
            numLados = lineas.elementAt(1).toInt()
            for (i in 2..numLados + 1){
                auxLado = lineas.elementAt(i).split(" ")
                aristaaux = Arista(auxLado.elementAt(0).toInt(), auxLado.elementAt(1).toInt())
                agregarArista(aristaaux)
            }
            

            fun agregarArista(a: Arista) {
                listaAdyacencias.elementAt(a.v).add(a.u)
                listaAristas.add(a)
            }
```

auxLado es solo una variable auxiliar para hacer un split de un string

aristaaux es una variable auxiliar para crear un elemento de tipo arista para agregarlo al grafo

listaAdyacencias es una MutableList

listavacia es una MutableList vacia que use para añadir una lista vacía a cada casilla de listaAdyacencias

a.v y a.u son enteros que representan los vertices inicial y final de una arista en ese orden